# Is this Categorical Distribution a valid proposal for Metropolis Hastings?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Is it possible to use a categorical distribution as proposal distribution for Metropolis-Hastings?

For example, suppose that at the current iteration we are at the state $x_{i}=1$, from which there are $(1,2,3,4,5)$ other possible states that we can move to with probabilities $p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}, p_{4}, p_{5}$.

Next from $x_{i}$ we decide to move to $x_{i+1}=2$. The proposal distribution of this movement can be regarded as categorical and write that
$$q(x_{i+1}=2|x_{i}=1)=p_{2}$$
??

For the opposite movement, from $x_{i+1}=2$ we can move to states $(1,2,3,4,6)$ with probabilities $p^{'}_{1}, p^{'}_{2}, p^{'}_{3}, p^{'}_{4}, p^{'}_{6})$, then the proposal distribution can be regard as
$$q(x_{i}=1|x_{i+1}=2)=p^{'}_{1}$$
??

Comment: One need specify the Markov transition from any state to any state used by the proposal transition.

Comment: @Xi'an So, I'll define the proposal from $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ to $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$. However, for the movement $\rightarrow$ the proposal $p_{6}$ will be zero and for the reverse the proposal $p^{'}_{5}$ will be zero?

Comment: You don't need to use Metropolis-Hastings (necessarily) to to MCMC. You'll need to construct a proposal distribution so that you can prove that the stationary distribution is your target distribution. MH is one way of doing that. If you want to stick with MH maybe some details here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Formal_derivation) can help you design an appropriate proposal.

Comment: @bdeonovic essentially what is really needed to hold is the detailed balance as I understand ?

Comment: @Fiodor1234: I do not understand the question in your reply.

Comment: @Fiodor1234, you must construct a proposal distribution such that you you can show that the stationary distribution exists and is unique. Detailed balance is sufficient to show existance. The MH describes a process for constructing such a proposal distribution, but as I said MH is not the only way to construct such a proposal.